# What causes an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java

```
    //Palindrone from a String
public class Palindrome {
    static int track = 0;
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String str = "abcicbbcdefggfed ";
        char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
        Palindrome p1 = new Palindrome();
        p1.find_palindrome(charArray);
    }
    void find_palindrome(char[] ch){
        for(int i=0; i< ch.length; i++){
            if(ch[i] == ch[i+1]){
                checkPalindrome(ch, i, i+1);                
            }
            else{
                checkPalindrome(ch,i-1,i+1);
            }
        }       
    }
    void checkPalindrome(char[] c, int left, int right){
        int count=0,l=0,r=0;
        while(left >= 0 && right <= c.length){
            while(c[left] == c[right]){
                left--;
                right++;
                count = count + 1;
            }
            break;
        }
        if(count > track){
            track = count;
            l = left;
            r = right;
        }
        if(count>1){
            for (int j=left+1;j<=right-1;j++){
                System.out.println(c[j]);
            }       
            System.out.println("--");
        }       
    }
}
```

I am seeing the given exception error and I don't know how to solve. I know its beginner question, so an explanation along with your answer would really help.

**Edit:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 17
    at Palindrome.find_palindrome(Palindrome.java:14)
    at Palindrome.main(Palindrome.java:8)
```

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are *zero-based* in Java (And most languages). This means, that if you have an array of size `N`, then the indexes are from `0 ... N - 1`.

Your problem is here:

```
for(int i=0; i< ch.length; i++){
      if(ch[i] == ch[i+1])
```

What happens when `i = ch.length - 1`? What `i + 1` will be?

Lets assume `ch.length` is 10, means that indexes are from `0` to `9`, then `ch.length - 1` is `9`, but `i + 1` is `10`, which is out of bounds.

Comment: If Array length is 10, means that indexes are from 0 to 9, right?

Comment: @CodeEnthusiastic Sure, thanks. (Downvoting because of this is redundant IMHO).

Comment: I edited your answer then I see my edit is gone and you revised your answer. Downvoted because the answer *fails* if you say indexes are from `0` to `10`. Now upvoting, though.

Comment: @CodeEnthusiastic I rollback it by mistake, you can edit it if needed again, thanks for your efforts, appreciated.

Comment: okay, thanks for the information, So what I did is used another variable j for that, but still I am getting the exception, I earlier forgot to mention on which lines I am getting this exception. So I have edited the question. @MarounMaroun

Answer (score 1):

I think this statement is causing the exception:

```
        if(ch[i] == ch[i+1])
```

when you call it using the value of i just less than the length. This statement will cause the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`. The first and last index of an array `a` is `a[0]` and        `a[a.length -1]` respectively.

Comment: Yes that is the culprit :)